# Why the function is not read when I call it?

Tags: javascript, html, function, parameters, prompt

I'm French (sorry for my English) ***new in the web development even more in Javascript..***

I created a function named "***manyStyles***".

This function **have to grab an element** with **querySelector**(""), then **apply some style to the element grabbed before.** It's a really simple function,just to trial and learn.

The logical of the script is :

-I created **4 variables** with **function prompt("")** inside them; => The value of the user is ***stocked in those 4 variables.***

```
let askForElement= prompt("Type some selectors, with CSS synthax.. example:h1,h2.. #test(id) or .test(class)");
let askingHeight= prompt("Type some value for the height");
let askingWidth= prompt("Type some value for the width");
let askingBackgroundColor= prompt("Type some value for the background-color ex:red,green,blue, #66a ..");
```

-I declare my function **manyStyles** with 4 parameters(variables) inside the parentheses (elementGrab,elem_height,elem_width,element_bg_color) => elementGrab is used to catch the element like I explained before and the others parameters is variables for style.

```
function manyStyles(elementGrab,elem_height,elem_width,element_bg_color){
    let grabbedElement;
    grabbedElement=document.body.querySelector(`${elementGrab}`);
    document.body.grabbedElement.style=`height:${elem_height}px;width:${elem_width}px;background-color:${element_bg_color};`;
}
```

=>**Inside the body function I just create a variable named "grabbedElement" to store inside it the element when is going to be grabbed just the in the statement following.**

**At the end I call the function with her name and in the parameters I put the 4 variables prompt** (that created in the first step);

```
manyStyles(askForElement,askingHeight,askingWidth,askingBackgroundColor);
```

Normally the function have to grab element with **querySelcetor** and then apply to it the styles.

But for some reason is doesn't work

Look at the complete code is more explaining ..

Thank You

```js
let askForElement= prompt("Type some selectors, with CSS synthax.. example:h1,h2.. #test(id) or .test(class)");
let askingHeight= prompt("Type some value for the height");
let askingWidth= prompt("Type some value for the width");
let askingBackgroundColor= prompt("Type some value for the background-color ex:red,green,blue, #66a ..");


function manyStyles(elementGrab,elem_height,elem_width,element_bg_color){
    let grabbedElement;
    grabbedElement=document.body.querySelector(`${elementGrab}`);
    document.body.grabbedElement.style=`height:${elem_height}px;width:${elem_width}px;background-color:${element_bg_color};`;
}

manyStyles(askForElement,askingHeight,askingWidth,askingBackgroundColor);
```

Comment: You've explained everything but the actual problem (and no _"But for some reason is doesn't work"_ is not a sufficient problem/error description). What happens instead of the expected behavior? Any errors in the console?

Comment: I console.log the line when I call the function, the console write:
=> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'style' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a variable inside with `let grabbedElement` you assigned it the grabbed element but then you have not used it. It should be like this, where you change grabbed element.

```js
grabbedElement.style=`height:${elem_height}px;width:${elem_width}px;background-color:${element_bg_color};`;
```

You trying to get `styles` from `document.body.grabbedElement` but `document.body.grabbedElement` doesn't exist there.

Comment: Thank you bro, it's working..
Just I have some troubles with VS Code and he colored the things strangely..
Anyway, Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

On first look what you are doing is create a variable, but then you don't use this variable to set style. `document.body.grabbedElement` equals to `undefined`.

```
function manyStyles(elementGrab,elem_height,elem_width,element_bg_color){
   let grabbedElement=document.body.querySelector(`${elementGrab}`);
   grabbedElement.style=`height:${elem_height}px;width:${elem_width}px;background-color:${element_bg_color};`;
}
```